# Python - Compare two sets and return if one of the sets is bigger

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have created a script where I compare two sets where there is one called:

```
old_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', }
new_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', 'Yay' }
```

My thought with the script is to return the value whenever new_sets is "bigger" than old_sets.

So I tried to create something like:

```
changed_grades = [old_count in old_sets ) if len(old_sets) < len(new_sets)]

return changed_grades
```

but I totally got it wrong and here I am... :(

My question is: how can I make it so it returns whenever the new_dict is bigger than old_setsand ignore if old_dict is bigger than new_sets? - Meaning it doesn't matter what values are inside the sets but the length of it. etc:

```
old_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', } - Len 3
new_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', 'Yay' } - Len 4 <-- Print out becuase it has bigger set than old_set
```

edit: My whole function:

```
def getChanges(old_sets, new_sets):

    longest_set_length = max(len(old_sets), len(new_sets))
    new_items = new_sets - old_sets

    return new_list

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

def check_difference():

    old_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow'}

    while True:

        new_sets  = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', 'Yay'}

        grab_changes = getChanges(old_sets, new_sets)

        if grab_changes....: #Something
            #if there is changes where new_values

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(10, 20)
            print("No new changes")
            old_sets = new_sets
            time.sleep(randomtime)
```

So as you can see, what I wanted to do (maybe this is even unnecessary) but I wanted to call `getChanges(old_sets, new_sets)` where this function checks if new_sets is bigger than old_sets and returns if it is true. If not then we just hit the

```
else:
   randomtime = random.randint(10, 20)
   print("No new changes")
   old_sets = new_sets
   time.sleep(randomtime)
```

Comment: Btw, `old_dict` and `new_dict` are not `dictionaries`, they are `sets`.

Comment: Oh god! I will change that right away! I always thought it was dict. @BrunoLubascher

Comment: In this case `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6, 7}` which set is bigger? If you're comparing sets only based on length you can simply compare `len(set1)` and `len(set2)`. If you want to check if one set is a subset of the other you should clarify your question.

Comment: I just edited to clarify my question! Hopefully its better now! @BiBi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max` with an appropriate "key" function:

```
return max(old_set, new_set, key=len)
```

Normally, `a > b` for sets `a` and `b` is true if `a` is a superset of `b`. Using `len` for the "key" function changes the comparison to `len(a) > len(b)`.

Comment: Alright so I tried this function. Basically what happend is that it returns even thought the value is the same or even if a is bigger than b and b is bigger than a. Meaning it prints out out all the time. Shouldn't it only print if b is bigger than a like I asked?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the length of the largest set in terms of `length`, then you can have:

```
longest_set_length = max(len(old_set), len(new_set))
```

Also, now that you know you have **sets** you can use set operations to make your life easier.

For example, you if you want to know which items were added to the **new_set** you can do:

```
new_items = new_set - old_set
```

## Edit given comments

#### First

You need to define a function `get_number_of_new_items(old_set, new_set)`.

As I see, you have two choices:

```
def number_of_new_items(old_set, new_set):
    return max(len(new_set) - len(old_set), 0)
```

or

```
def number_of_new_items(old_set, new_set):
    return len(new_set - new_set)
```

Suppose you have:

```
old_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', }
new_sets = {'My', 'name', 'is'}
```

The **first** implementation would say that `number_of_new_items == 0` and the **second** implementation would say that `number_of_new_items == 3`. So it is your choice.

#### Second

Use the function in your loop:

```
def check_difference():

    old_sets = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow'}

    while True:

        new_sets  = {'Hello', 'Stack', 'overflow', 'Yay'}

        n_new_items = number_of_new_items(old_sets, new_sets)

        if n_new_items > 0: #Something
            #if there is changes where new_values

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(10, 20)
            print("No new changes")
            old_sets = new_sets
            time.sleep(randomtime)
```

Comment: That was pretty neat I would say! Althrough I can't really get a grip when it comes to `max(len(old_set), len(new_set))` Seems like it writes the higher number even if old_set is bigger than new_set. What I wanted basically only is that if new_set is bigger than old_set then we return :)

Comment: @Hellosiroverthere Post your **whole** function in the question. No body is understanding what you want. Seems that you have a problem with the `return` and not with the logic...

Comment: There we go! I just added my function. I have a feeling that I overcomplicate the function more than it actually should

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the number of elements in the sets, you can simply compare their lengths with

```
if len(old_sets) < len(new_sets):
    print(new_sets)
```